# PDII certification

Tags: developer, certification, platform-developer-2

I have completed all four of the super badges, `Apex Specialist`, `Data Integration Specialist`, `Lightning Component Framework Specialist`, and `Advanced Apex Specialist`.

Is it OK to appear for the proctored based multiple-choice exam for PDII or I have to first clear the multiple-choice exam and then only need to go for 4 super badges?

I have the Platform Developer I (PDI) certification which is prerequisite of PDII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Platform Developer II certification page](http://certification.salesforce.com/platformdeveloperII), you can do the Trailhead super badges and the PDII Proctored multi-choice exam independently.

There is no requirement to do the exam before or after the superbadges. Only that you need to complete all the superbadges and the exam to get the certification.

[image]

Comment: Sorry @Daniel Ballinger. We both were writing the answer at the same time. I can delete mine. :)

Comment: @the_phantom No problem, it happens.

Comment: To provide some background info, I had actually first completed the trailhead superbadges and then the mutliple choice exam. Received the email to link the webassessor and trailhead accounts few days later and then all set! Just make sure that you have access to the email accounts associated with both webassessor and trailhead.

Comment: @JayantDas Will there would be issue if I don't have same email id for webassessor and trailhead?

Comment: @Avijit Make sure you link the webassessor and Trailhead accounts as per the [instructions](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Changes-to-Platform-Developer-II).  It should be fine to have different emails for both as long as they are linked.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Got your point.

Comment: @Avijit, as DanielBallinger has already mentioned that it can be different, just want to add to it based on my recent experience. You don't need to have same email on the accounts. But just make sure you have access to the ones you have in there. Like I did not have access to the email associated with my trailhead, so had to create a new trailhead profile, merge it and then proceed with account linking procedure.

Comment: @JayantDas: Yes point is noted.